# Event triggers only once

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm using OxyPlot for animating a simple sinusoidal motion:

```
       void ViewMotion()
    {
        foreach (File item in LoadedFiles())
        {
            LineSeries skeleton = new LineSeries();
            skeleton.MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle;
            skeleton.MarkerSize = 10;

            AnimationPlot.Series.Add(skeleton );

            var worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };

            foreach (Channel node in item.ChannelAnim)
            {
                double x = 0;
                worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
                {
                    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        x += 0.02;
                        if (skeleton.Points.Count > 0)
                        {
                            skeleton.Points.Remove(ss.Points.First());
                        }

                        skeleton.Points.Add(new DataPoint(50, 50 + (30 + x) * Math.Sin(x)));
                        AnimationPlot.RefreshPlot(true);
                        MessageBox.Show("");
                        Thread.Sleep(25);

                    }
                };

            }
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();


        }
    }
```

Basically is just a dot going up and down.
The problem that the event only triggers once, so I don't see a motion but the initial position. It's not a binding problem, it is something wrong with the event. I've tried changing the order but without success.

By the way, this is working correctly:
(Two dots going up and down)

```
    ScatterSeries ss = new ScatterSeries();
    ScatterSeries ss2 = new ScatterSeries();
    public void TemporalMethod(object param)
    {
        ss.MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle;
        ss.MarkerSize = 20;
        ss.MarkerFill = OxyColors.Violet;
        MyModel.Series.Add(ss);

        ss2.MarkerType = MarkerType.Triangle;
        ss2.MarkerSize = 20;
        ss2.MarkerFill = OxyColors.Green;
        MyModel.Series.Add(ss2);

        var worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;

        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            while (!worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                x += 0.02;
                y += 0.001;
                if (ss.Points.Count > 0)
                {
                    ss.Points.Remove(ss.Points.First());
                }
                if (ss2.Points.Count > 0)
                {
                    ss2.Points.Remove(ss2.Points.First());
                }

                ss.Points.Add(new DataPoint(50, 50 + (30 + x) * Math.Sin(x)));
                ss2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(55, 50 + 30 * Math.Sin(x + y)));
                MyModel.RefreshPlot(true);

                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

EDIT: The solution is pretty dumb, I mistakenly wrote

```
                            if (skeleton.Points.Count > 0)
                        {
                            skeleton.Points.Remove(ss.Points.First());
                        }
```

instead of:

```
                            if (skeleton.Points.Count > 0)
                        {
                            skeleton.Points.Remove(skeleton.Points.First());
                        }
```

I don't know why but I haven't got any errors.

Comment: `OxyPlot for animating a simple sinusoidal motion`... Bless you. ;)

Comment: You are not using the variable node in your inner foreach loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, I'm developing the method, it's not finished yet.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, put the solution as an answer. After a day or so you can accept it. Do not put the answer in the question or put "Solved" in the title, that does not mark it as solved in the UI.